# Been using Ubuntu For about a week. Trying to run 2-5 Game Servers. Need some advice

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, xubuntu, games

So, I don't know whether or not I should use Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server. The game servers will be hosting 2-3 CSGO servers(11slots each), Teamspeak, and possibly a rust or another game server. My question is will it make THAT much of a difference to run these dedicated servers in the Desktop Ubuntu(User-interface makes it so easy) verses Server Ubuntu(Way harder than I thought)?

Comment: You could always install a GUI/DE on Server Ubuntu.

Comment: I actually did that but got fed-up with the lack of resolution control. I could for the life of me get it to change. Used "hwinfo --framebuffer" and "xrandr etc..." and all that jazz. but I could never get it to change. 

What is the "DE" you are referring to?

Comment: DE = Desktop Environment. Resolution control should be independent of the Ubuntu type (desktop/server) that you choose - solely dependent on GUI/DE from what I understand. When you install a DE (for example unity (ubuntu's default) or xfce (my favorite) ) you should be able to find a utility called "Display". See http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available for more info.